# jedi infer() does not work with my custom AWS S3-based Python importer

Tags: python-jedi

I get a ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 1, got 0) exception when I'm trying to run jedi inside of AWS Lambda powered with my S3-based Python importer. I manged to make parso and jedi working with two small Python standard compliant patches, but with this one I feel clueless. Here is the stack trace, debug output and the test function code. It works locally. Any ideas where to look at would be highly appreciated. The ultimate goal is to explore possibilities of having a completely serverless Python IDE.

```
 1. Debug output and Stack trace:
dbg: Start: infer
dbg: infer_node <Name: variable@16,4>@(16, 4) in MixedModuleContext(<ModuleValue: __main__@2-16 is_stub=False>)
dbg: context.goto <Name: variable@16,4> in (MixedModuleContext(<ModuleValue: __main__@2-16 is_stub=False>)): [<TreeNameDefinition: string_name=variable start_pos=(15, 4)>]
dbg: global search_module 'builtins': <CompiledModule: <module 'builtins' (built-in)>>
dbg: infer_node PythonNode(atom, [<Operator: [>, PythonNode(testlist_comp, [<Name: keyword@15,17>, <Operator: ,>, <Name: f@15,26>, <Operator: ,>, <Name: C@15,29>, <Operator: ,>, <Name: x@15,32>]), <Operator: ]>])@(15, 16) in ModuleContext(<ModuleValue: __main__@2-16 is_stub=False>)
dbg: iterate <SequenceLiteralValue of PythonNode(atom, [<Operator: [>, PythonNode(testlist_comp, [<Name: keyword@15,17>, <Operator: ,>, <Name: f@15,26>, <Operator: ,>, <Name: C@15,29>, <Operator: ,>, <Name: x@15,32>]), <Operator: ]>])>
dbg: infer_node <Name: keyword@15,17>@(15, 17) in ModuleContext(<ModuleValue: __main__@2-16 is_stub=False>)
dbg: context.goto <Name: keyword@15,17> in (ModuleContext(<ModuleValue: __main__@2-16 is_stub=False>)): [<TreeNameDefinition: string_name=keyword start_pos=(2, 7)>]
dbg: global search_module 'keyword': <ModuleValue: keyword@3-95 is_stub=False>
dbg: after import: S{<ModuleValue: keyword@3-95 is_stub=False>}
dbg: context.names_to_types: [<TreeNameDefinition: string_name=keyword start_pos=(2, 7)>] -> S{<ModuleValue: keyword@3-95 is_stub=False>}
dbg: infer_node <Name: f@15,26>@(15, 26) in ModuleContext(<ModuleValue: __main__@2-16 is_stub=False>)
dbg: context.goto <Name: f@15,26> in (ModuleContext(<ModuleValue: __main__@2-16 is_stub=False>)): [<TreeNameDefinition: string_name=f start_pos=(12, 4)>]
dbg: context.names_to_types: [<TreeNameDefinition: string_name=f start_pos=(12, 4)>] -> S{<FunctionValue: <Function: f@12-14>>}
dbg: infer_node <Name: C@15,29>@(15, 29) in ModuleContext(<ModuleValue: __main__@2-16 is_stub=False>)
dbg: context.goto <Name: C@15,29> in (ModuleContext(<ModuleValue: __main__@2-16 is_stub=False>)): [<TreeNameDefinition: string_name=C start_pos=(4, 6)>]
dbg: context.names_to_types: [<TreeNameDefinition: string_name=C start_pos=(4, 6)>] -> S{<ClassValue: <Class: C@4-6>>}
dbg: infer_node <Name: x@15,32>@(15, 32) in ModuleContext(<ModuleValue: __main__@2-16 is_stub=False>)
dbg: context.goto <Name: x@15,32> in (ModuleContext(<ModuleValue: __main__@2-16 is_stub=False>)): [<TreeNameDefinition: string_name=x start_pos=(10, 0)>]
dbg: infer_expr_stmt <ExprStmt: x = D()@10,0> (<Name: x@10,0>)
dbg: infer_node PythonNode(atom_expr, [<Name: D@10,4>, PythonNode(trailer, [<Operator: (>, <Operator: )>])])@(10, 4) in ModuleContext(<ModuleValue: __main__@2-16 is_stub=False>)
dbg: infer_node <Name: D@10,4>@(10, 4) in ModuleContext(<ModuleValue: __main__@2-16 is_stub=False>)
dbg: context.goto <Name: D@10,4> in (ModuleContext(<ModuleValue: __main__@2-16 is_stub=False>)): [<TreeNameDefinition: string_name=D start_pos=(7, 6)>]
dbg: context.names_to_types: [<TreeNameDefinition: string_name=D start_pos=(7, 6)>] -> S{<ClassValue: <Class: D@7-9>>}
dbg: infer_trailer: PythonNode(trailer, [<Operator: (>, <Operator: )>]) in S{<ClassValue: <Class: D@7-9>>}
dbg: execute: <ClassValue: <Class: D@7-9>> <TreeArguments: None>
dbg: context.goto 'object' in (<CompiledModule: <module 'builtins' (built-in)>>): [<CompiledName: (<CompiledValueName: string_name=builtins>).object>]
dbg: context.names_to_types: [<CompiledName: (<CompiledValueName: string_name=builtins>).object>] -> S{<CompiledValue: <class 'object'>>}
dbg: execute result: S{<TreeInstance of <ClassValue: <Class: D@7-9>>(<TreeArguments: None>)>} in <ClassValue: <Class: D@7-9>>
dbg: infer_expr_stmt result S{<TreeInstance of <ClassValue: <Class: D@7-9>>(<TreeArguments: None>)>}
dbg: context.names_to_types: [<TreeNameDefinition: string_name=x start_pos=(10, 0)>] -> S{<TreeInstance of <ClassValue: <Class: D@7-9>>(<TreeArguments: None>)>}
dbg: Dynamic array search for <SequenceLiteralValue of PythonNode(atom, [<Operator: [>, PythonNode(testlist_comp, [<Name: keyword@15,17>, <Operator: ,>, <Name: f@15,26>, <Operator: ,>, <Name: C@15,29>, <Operator: ,>, <Name: x@15,32>]), <Operator: ]>])>
dbg: Start: Resolve lazy value wrapper
dbg: iterate <SequenceLiteralValue of PythonNode(atom, [<Operator: [>, PythonNode(testlist_comp, [<Name: keyword@15,17>, <Operator: ,>, <Name: f@15,26>, <Operator: ,>, <Name: C@15,29>, <Operator: ,>, <Name: x@15,32>]), <Operator: ]>])>
dbg: global search_module 'types': <ModuleValue: types@1-267 is_stub=False>
Module: S{<ModuleValue: types@1-267 is_stub=False>}
dbg: context.goto 'FunctionType' in (<ModuleValue: types@1-267 is_stub=False>): [<TreeNameDefinition: string_name=FunctionType start_pos=(12, 0)>]
dbg: infer_expr_stmt <ExprStmt: FunctionType = type(_f)@12,0> (<Name: FunctionType@12,0>)
dbg: infer_node PythonNode(atom_expr, [<Name: type@12,15>, PythonNode(trailer, [<Operator: (>, <Name: _f@12,20>, <Operator: )>])])@(12, 15) in ModuleContext(<ModuleValue: types@1-267 is_stub=False>)
dbg: infer_node <Name: type@12,15>@(12, 15) in ModuleContext(<ModuleValue: types@1-267 is_stub=False>)
dbg: context.goto <Name: type@12,15> in (ModuleContext(<ModuleValue: types@1-267 is_stub=False>)): [<CompiledName: (<CompiledValueName: string_name=builtins>).type>]
dbg: context.names_to_types: [<CompiledName: (<CompiledValueName: string_name=builtins>).type>] -> S{<CompiledValue: <class 'type'>>}
dbg: infer_trailer: PythonNode(trailer, [<Operator: (>, <Name: _f@12,20>, <Operator: )>]) in S{<CompiledValue: <class 'type'>>}
dbg: infer_node <Name: _f@12,20>@(12, 20) in ModuleContext(<ModuleValue: types@1-267 is_stub=False>)
dbg: context.goto <Name: _f@12,20> in (ModuleContext(<ModuleValue: types@1-267 is_stub=False>)): [<TreeNameDefinition: string_name=_f start_pos=(11, 4)>]
dbg: context.names_to_types: [<TreeNameDefinition: string_name=_f start_pos=(11, 4)>] -> S{<FunctionValue: <Function: _f@11-12>>}
dbg: builtin start <CompiledValue: <class 'type'>>
Module: S{<ModuleValue: types@1-267 is_stub=False>}
dbg: context.goto 'FunctionType' in (<ModuleValue: types@1-267 is_stub=False>): [<TreeNameDefinition: string_name=FunctionType start_pos=(12, 0)>]
warning: catched stmt recursion: <ExprStmt: FunctionType = type(_f)@12,0> @(12, 0)
dbg: context.names_to_types: [<TreeNameDefinition: string_name=FunctionType start_pos=(12, 0)>] -> S{}
Name: S{}
dbg: End: Resolve lazy value wrapper
dbg: End: infer
not enough values to unpack (expected 1, got 0): ValueError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/index.py", line 17, in handle_event
    return _test_infer_type()
  File "./service/python/_test_infer_type.py", line 34, in _test_infer_type
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/api/helpers.py", line 482, in wrapper
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/api/__init__.py", line 311, in infer
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/api/__init__.py", line 331, in _infer
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/api/helpers.py", line 164, in infer
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/__init__.py", line 179, in infer
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/helpers.py", line 80, in infer_call_of_leaf
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/context.py", line 222, in infer_node
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/syntax_tree.py", line 156, in infer_node
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/syntax_tree.py", line 169, in _infer_node_if_inferred
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/cache.py", line 44, in wrapper
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/syntax_tree.py", line 174, in _infer_node_cached
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/debug.py", line 82, in wrapper
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/syntax_tree.py", line 82, in wrapper
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/syntax_tree.py", line 184, in _infer_node
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/syntax_tree.py", line 309, in infer_atom
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/context.py", line 75, in py__getattribute__
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/base_value.py", line 414, in from_sets
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/context.py", line 75, in <genexpr>
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/names.py", line 282, in infer
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/plugins/__init__.py", line 21, in wrapper
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/plugins/stdlib.py", line 844, in wrapper
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/syntax_tree.py", line 741, in tree_name_to_values
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/base_value.py", line 298, in iterate_values
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/base_value.py", line 414, in from_sets
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/base_value.py", line 297, in <genexpr>
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/base_value.py", line 466, in iterate
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/value/iterable.py", line 361, in py__iter__
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/value/dynamic_arrays.py", line 40, in check_array_additions
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/cache.py", line 44, in wrapper
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/debug.py", line 82, in wrapper
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/value/dynamic_arrays.py", line 76, in _internal_check_array_additions
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/value/iterable.py", line 190, in name
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/compiled/value.py", line 423, in __init__
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/base_value.py", line 320, in __getattr__
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/utils.py", line 75, in wrapper
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/cache.py", line 111, in wrapper
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/base_value.py", line 328, in _wrapped_value
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/value/iterable.py", line 205, in _get_wrapped_value
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/cache.py", line 44, in wrapper
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/value/iterable.py", line 197, in _cached_generics
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/value/iterable.py", line 338, in _get_generics
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/value/iterable.py", line 193, in _get_generics
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/base_value.py", line 461, in py__class__
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/base_value.py", line 398, in __init__
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/base_value.py", line 461, in <genexpr>
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/value/function.py", line 164, in py__class__
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/helpers.py", line 198, in values_from_qualified_names
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/base_value.py", line 481, in py__getattribute__
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/base_value.py", line 414, in from_sets
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/base_value.py", line 481, in <genexpr>
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/base_value.py", line 81, in py__getattribute__
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/base_value.py", line 414, in from_sets
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/base_value.py", line 81, in <genexpr>
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/names.py", line 282, in infer
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/plugins/__init__.py", line 21, in wrapper
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/plugins/stdlib.py", line 844, in wrapper
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/syntax_tree.py", line 746, in tree_name_to_values
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/syntax_tree.py", line 82, in wrapper
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/syntax_tree.py", line 384, in infer_expr_stmt
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/debug.py", line 82, in wrapper
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/syntax_tree.py", line 417, in _infer_expr_stmt
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/context.py", line 222, in infer_node
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/syntax_tree.py", line 156, in infer_node
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/syntax_tree.py", line 169, in _infer_node_if_inferred
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/cache.py", line 44, in wrapper
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/syntax_tree.py", line 174, in _infer_node_cached
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/debug.py", line 82, in wrapper
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/syntax_tree.py", line 82, in wrapper
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/syntax_tree.py", line 208, in _infer_node
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/syntax_tree.py", line 280, in infer_trailer
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/base_value.py", line 472, in execute
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/base_value.py", line 414, in from_sets
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/base_value.py", line 472, in <genexpr>
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/plugins/__init__.py", line 21, in wrapper
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/plugins/stdlib.py", line 131, in wrapper
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/plugins/stdlib.py", line 173, in wrapper
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/plugins/stdlib.py", line 219, in builtins_type
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/base_value.py", line 461, in py__class__
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/base_value.py", line 398, in __init__
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/base_value.py", line 461, in <genexpr>
  File "/tmp/tmp9_1lc7fp/lib/python/jedi/inference/value/function.py", line 164, in py__class__
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 1, got 0)

 2. Test Function Code:

 from jedi import settings, Interpreter, debug

settings.cache_directory = '/tmp'
debug.debug_function = debug.print_to_stdout
debug.enable_warning = True
debug.enable_notice = True
namespaces = [locals()]

source_1 = '''
import keyword

class C:
    pass

class D:
    pass

x = D()

def f():
    pass

for variable in [keyword, f, C, x]:
    variable'''

source_2 = '''
import json
json.lo'''


def _test_infer_type():
    '''test type inference'''
    script = Interpreter(source_1, namespaces)
    defs = sorted(script.infer(), key=lambda d: d.line)
    types = [str(d.type) for d in defs]
    assert(['module', 'class', 'instance', 'function'] == types)

    return 'OK'
```

Comment: This is probably an issue in Jedi and you should open an issue on the Github Jedi tracker. Make sure to use the latest master first, to check if the issue was already fixed.

Comment: Submitted to the tissue tracker #1591. Thx.